# Temporary disconnection of wireless headset mutes VLC's (and only VLC's) audio until VLC is rewound. How to debug?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, vlc-media-player, headset, wireless-headset

When I am wearing my wireless headset and I walk outside of its range for just a moment (enough for me to not be able to hear the audio, but not enough for a permanent wireless disconnect), VLC will continue playing the video but with muted audio until I rewind the video. This only happens with VLC. I do not get the same issue in Firefox.

I use the ALSA Audio Output. I use this because the default option, PulseAudio, causes audio to be skipped at high playback rates.

How can I debug this muting issue?

My OS is Xubuntu 23.10. My VLC version is 3.0.18 Vetinari.

Comment: Does [this](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=123042#p531038) pertain to the problem or can affect it in any way?

Comment: @harrymc Interesting. After trying that, I could no longer replicate the issue. That might have fixed it? Very strange.

Comment: If it continues to work well, let me know and I'll put up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The videolan post
[Turn off audio normalization altogether?](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=123042)
contains a surprising
[answer by user Francewhoa](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=123042#p531038)
which seems (for the moment) to have helped with the problem.

The explanation given in the answer is that this is a Linux problem,
and not a VLC problem.
The workaround in Debian with GNOME, was to modify the volume
for VLC in a random manner, and this has unblocked whatever
was the problem.
(The screen is in French, where in English "Paramétres"
means "Parameters" and "Son" means "Sound".)

[image]